# Wordpress - Nested Shortcode from 2 different plugins half working

Tags: wordpress, nested, shortcode

I am trying to use the Print This Section plugin with WP-Invoice and have been struggling for days now trying to figure out where the problem is?

With Both WP-invoice installed and working and WP Print This section also installed and working. On my Invoice page I have used
    [print_this]
    [wp-invoice]
    [/print_this]

This displays perfectly the WP-invoice shortcode is read and processed and displays inside the Print this section box.

The problem is when I click the "Print This" button the page that opens up actually displays the text [wp-invoice] and not the actual invoice?

I have been all over the net and tried many things to do with nested shortcodes, from what I can tell I need a "do_shortcode($content)" somewhere but I can't figure out where?

A link to the sample invoice and problem:
http://www.yourtechally.com/client-login/invoice-online/?invoice_id=ef77a582808c0973b62d79f40059ce30

Answer (score 0):

```
$code=do_shortcode('[wp-invoice]');
$shortcode='[print_this]'.$code.'[/print_this]';
do_shortcode($shortcode);
```

Try this, it could be the solution.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response... but where do I put this code..?

Comment: In the php page where you want to display the content, just add the above lines and use teh last line for echoing the output. echo do_shortcode($shortcode); and make sure to place them within php tags

Comment: Hmm that didnt seem to work for me, but I have managed to track down exactly which PHP file is being used for the printable page and i think the line in that PHP that is reading the page content is
<div id="BlogContent"><?php extract_content(); ?></div>
but all that returns is the [wp-invoice] text not the contents of that shortcode ?

Comment: could you specify a bit more of the code, and is it a template?